# Configure asp.net mvc hocalhost/Home/Products to hocalhost/Products

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to configure asp.net mvc routing to get

hocalhost/Products and hocalhost/Search

instead of

hocalhost/Home/Products and hocalhost/Home/Search

i.e. to remove **Controller** name from the route?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Products", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Products", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Thus:

```
http://example.com/ => controller=Home, action=Products
http://example.com/Products => contoller=Home, action=Products
http://example.com/Search => contoller=Home, action=Search
```